# React nothing executed after post with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm having trouble getting anything after an axios post to execute. The data posts to the backend as expected, but I can't get anything to run afterwards. Even a console.log after the post doesn't work. I've tried promise and async await based axios and I can't get anything after the post via axios to run. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Create React App 3.3.0

React 16.11

React Router 5.1.2

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import axios from 'axios'

...

class Contact extends Component {
      ...

    submitContactHandler = async event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.post('/mail/contact', {
                userName: this.state.formData.name.value,
                userEmail: this.state.formData.email.value,
                userMessage: this.state.formData.message.value
            })
            this.props.history.push('/about')
            console.log("This doesn't even run")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    render() {
        ...
        return (
            ...
            <Form onSubmit = {(event) => this.submitContactHandler(event)}>
                ...
            </Form >
        ...
        )
      }
    }

export default withRouter(Contact)
```

Comment: Have tried both relative and absolute paths in `axios.post()`. `console.log()` works fine in the `try` block if executed before the `axios.post()` but not after.

Comment: There should be an error in that try catch. Have you seen one? `console.log("err:", error)` for better visibility

Comment: That's what I'd expect as well, but that is not the case. I'm logging `console.log(this.props)` above the try/catch block, and that is executed fine, though it remains the only thing displaying in the browser console. App terminal is only displaying success logs as expected. I'm stumped.

Comment: try console logging that this.props.history if it returns something

Comment: ```{length: 8, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
length: 8
action: "POP"
location: {pathname: "/contact", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}
createHref: ƒ createHref(location)
push: ƒ push(path, state)
replace: ƒ replace(path, state)
go: ƒ go(n)
goBack: ƒ goBack()
goForward: ƒ goForward()
block: ƒ block(prompt)
listen: ƒ listen(listener)
__proto__: Object```

Comment: Redirect works fine `this.props.history.push('/about')` if I comment out the try/catch with the post request.

Comment: shouldn't you depend on the response of the server? if it is either success then do a redirect. if not, then do some warning?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to accomplish. Post data, wait for response from server, then redirect to a confirmation page or display the error. The problem is I can't get anything to execute after the post request via axios.

Comment: I've commented below that might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the response from backend

```
   await axios.post('/mail/contact', {
       userName: this.state.formData.name.value,
       userEmail: this.state.formData.email.value,
      userMessage: this.state.formData.message.value
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.props.history.push('/about')
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the `res.json` was commented out in the backend for this particular post request. /sigh. You directed me to the fix, thank you.